# A program that prints even and odd characters from a string

Tags: c, arrays, string

**This is for Homework**

I have to write a program that asks the user to enter a string, then my program would separate the even and odd values from the entered string. Here is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *str[41];
    char odd[21];
    char even[21];
    int i = 0; 
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    printf("Enter a string (40 characters maximum): ");
    scanf("%s", &str);

    while (&str[i] < 41) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            odd[j++] = *str[i];
        } else {
            even[k++] = *str[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    printf("The even string is:%s\n ", even);
    printf("The odd string is:%s\n ", odd);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try and compile my program I get two warnings:

1. For my `scanf` I get `"format '%s' expects arguments of type char but argument has 'char * (*)[41]"`. I'm not sure what this means but I assume it's because of the array initialization.
2. On the `while` loop it gives me the warning that says comparison between pointer and integer. I'm not sure what that means either and I thought it was legal in C to make that comparison.

When I compile the program, I get random characters for both the even and odd string.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `scanf("%s" , &str);` -> `scanf("%s" , str);`

Comment: `char *str[41];` => `char str[41];` then remove all dereferencing of `str` (*str)

Comment: `scanf("%s" , &str);` -> `scanf("%40s" , str);`

Comment: That might be one line of the code fixed!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sorry I didn't specify in my post, but the assignment requires for me to use the string where everything is entered as a pointer

Comment: In C, arrays have many of the same properties as pointers.

Comment: You'll also want to stop scanning the input string when reaching the last character which could well be less than 40 characters in.

Comment: @chrisHG Yes, you should have mentioned that up front:(  Anyway, handling 'strings' by means of char* does not mean that you have to put '&' in front of every variable reference!

Comment: `if (i % 2 == 0) {
        odd[j++] = str[i];` looks like it should be `if (i % 2 == 0) {
        even[j++] = str[i];`

Comment: please edit your answer as you want to print the characters which is on place odd or even, not the values :)

Comment: @JayJoshi you mean "edit your question" [edit]... yes, if the evenness is tested on string contents, that's pretty different (but an easy fix)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this declaration is wrong:

```
char *str[41];
```

you're declaring 41 uninitialized strings. You want:

```
char str[41];
```

then, `scanf("%40s" , str);`, no `&` and limit the input size (safety)

then the loop (where your `while (str[i]<41)` is wrong, it probably ends at once since letters start at 65 (ascii code for "A"). You wanted to test `i` against 41 but test `str[i]` against `\0` instead, else you get all the garbage after nul-termination char in one of `odd` or `even` strings if the string is not exactly 40 bytes long)

```
while (str[i]) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        odd[j++] = str[i];
    } else {
        even[k++] = str[i];
    }
    i++;
}
```

if you want to use a *pointer* (assignement requirement), just define `str` as before:

```
char str[41];
```

scan the input value on it as indicated above, then point on it:

```
char *p = str;
```

And now that you defined a pointer on a buffer, if you're required to use deference instead of index access you can do:

```
while (*p) { // test end of string termination
    if (i % 2 == 0) {  // if ((p-str) % 2 == 0) { would allow to get rid of i
        odd[j++] = *p;
    } else {
        even[k++] = *p;
    }
    p++;
    i++;
}
```

(we have to increase `i` for the even/odd test, or we would have to test `p-str` evenness)

aaaand last classical mistake (thanks to last-minute comments), `even` & `odd` aren't null terminated so the risk of getting garbage at the end when printing them, you need:

```
even[k] = odd[j] = '\0';
```

(as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272368/a-program-that-prints-even-and-odd-characters-from-a-string/47272518#47272518) states, check the concept of even & odd, the expected result may be the other way round)

Comment: I do not get the `while (str[i] < 41)`.

Comment: you're right, OP must test nul termination. I have added a safety check in my last rewrite, but the < 41 was useless and would probably do nothing useful except stopping the loop, since letters start at 65...

Comment: i < 41 isn't even correct, because the count will go beyond the string data and will count garbage after nul terminator.

Comment: @chqrlie yes, but see above: I advise OP to define a buffer then point on it.

Comment: Note: OP;s `printf("The even string is:%s\n ", even);` is printing an array that is not certainly null character terminated.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: OK, but it is confusing as you use the same identifier `str` as the OP for a different type. I would use `p` as a pointer and keep `str` as the array that contains a string.

Comment: @chqrlie also my last pointer solution was wrong, since `i` wasn't incremented anymore. I added it back, using pointer arithmetic here sounds a bit overkill.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You define an array of pointers `char *str[41]`, not an array of `char`.
- You should pass the array to `scanf` instead of its address: When passed to a function, an array decays into a pointer to its first element.
- You should limit the number of characters read by `scanf`.
- You should iterate until the end of the string, not on all elements of the array, especially with `(&str[i] < 41)` that compares the address of the `i`th element with the value `41`, which is meaningless.  The end of the string is the null terminator which can be tested with `(str[i] != '\0')`.
- You should read the characters from `str` with `str[i]`.
- You should null terminate the `even` and `odd` arrays.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[41];
    char odd[21];
    char even[21];
    int i = 0; 
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    printf("Enter a string (40 characters maximum): ");
    if (scanf("%40s", str) != 1)
        return 1;

    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            odd[j++] = str[i];
        } else {
            even[k++] = str[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    odd[j] = even[k] = '\0';

    printf("The even string is: %s\n", even);
    printf("The odd string is: %s\n", odd);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that your interpretation of even and odd characters assumes 1-based offsets, ie: the first character is an odd character. This is not consistent with the C approach where an even characters would be interpreted as having en even offset from the beginning of the string, starting at 0.

Comment: Just a question - For the even/odd big are we talking about the ASCII values or the characters '0' to '9' - Should be ignore 'A' etc...

Comment: @chqrlie "You should iterate until the end of the string, not on all characters": OP probably meant that, but actually OP tests `str[i]` against 41, so the loop probably ends at once, unless space or other lower ASCII chars are inputted. I didn't see why OP was doing that at first either...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: indeed, the comparison was contorted and meaningless. the OP actually compares the address of `str[i]` with `41`...

Answer (score 2):

here is your solution :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{

    char str[41]; 
    char odd[21];
    char even[21];
    int i = 0; 
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    printf("Enter a string (40 characters maximum): ");
    scanf("%s" , str); 

    while (i < strlen(str)) 
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
                odd[j++] = str[i];
        } else {
                even[k++] = str[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    odd[j] = '\0'; 
    even[k] = '\0';

    printf("The even string is:%s\n " , even);

    printf("The odd string is:%s\n " , odd);

    return 0;
}
```

solved the mistake in the declaration, the scanning string value, condition of the while loop and assignment of element of array. :)

Comment: @chux: actually, which array may not be null terminated depends on the length of the input ;-)

Comment: oh thank you for the suggestion. here.. i correct it

Comment: sometimes it is easy to get the solution quickly instead of much explanation. that's my try :D  ..he will surely figure out the problems.

Comment: this solution is wrong if the string entered isn't exactly 40 characters long.

Answer (score 2):

Many answers all ready point out the original code`s problems.

Below are some ideas to reduce memory usage as the 2 arrays `odd[], even[]` are not *needed*.

As the "even" characters are seen, print them out.
As the "odd" characters are seen, move them to the first part of the array.

Alternative print: If code used `"%.*s"`, the array does not need a null character termination.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char str[41];

  printf("Enter a string (40 characters maximum): ");
  fflush(stdout);
  if (scanf("%40s", str) == 1) {
    int i;
    printf("The even string is:");
    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        str[i / 2] = str[i];  // copy character to an earlier part of `str[]`
      } else {
        putchar(str[i]);
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("The odd string is:%.*s\n ", (i + 1) / 2, str);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

or simply

```
printf("The even string is:");
for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
  if (i % 2 != 0) {
    putchar(str[i]);
  }
}
printf("\n");
printf("The odd string is:");
for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    putchar(str[i]);
  }
}
printf("\n");
```